# C# and TPM Functions

Tags: c#, security, tpm

I've been endlessly searching the internet for an answer to this but unfortunately can't seem to find it anywhere.

I'm trying to run the equivalent of this PowerShell command in C#, but without having to import PowerShell libraries into my code:

Get-TpmEndorsementKeyInfo -hashalgorithm sha256

Basically, all I'm trying to get to is the SHA256 representation of my TPM EK. If possible, I'd also like to retrieve the Thumbprint of the same, as the PowerShell command gives when it's run.

I've tried working with Limpet (https://github.com/ms-iot/security/tree/master/Limpet/Limpet.NET) but to no avail.

Why do I need this? I'm trying to use TPM as a mechanism to prove a PC is unique, I could then use that hash which is unique to this computer's TPM device to do other functions including possibly licensing. Either way, I'm trying to do this in C#.

Ideally I also find a way to sign messages using C# and TPM but I'll keep searching for that.

Any clues?

Comment: Do you also not want to just invoke Powershell as a standalone process and read the output (through C#)?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks for that suggestion! The problem is that unfortunately once I start calling PowerShell either via standalone process or by importing the PowerShell library, my AV triggers a false positive every time. I want to avoid that if possible but you're absolutely right, that is an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know the class is defined in an assembly that is in an Azure SDK, but you could have a look at the [SecurityProviderTpmHsm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.provisioning.security.securityprovidertpmhsm?view=azure-dotnet) class which is defined in the Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Security.Tpm package.